# serialize query from Nest client elastic search 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Since upgrading my Nest client to 2.2.1 I'm unable see the query I'm submitting to my elastic search client (now version 2.3.0). 
I used to use this line:

```
string searchJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.Serializer.Serialize(myQueryHere));
```

But this method now returns void instead of the JSON it used to.
ConnectionStatus also doesn't exist so I can no longer see the json i'm sending, does anyone know of a way?  CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes is available but that returns null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Take a look at the documentation for NEST 2.x on Connecting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/connecting.html#CO1-1). `CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes` will be `null` unless you set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings` that is passed to the constructor of `ElasticClient`

```
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));  
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool) 
    .DisableDirectStreaming();

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

now a copy of the request and response bytes will be exposed on the response CallDetails

```
var response = client.Search<Document>();

var requestJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes);
var responseJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.CallDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes);
```

[Whilst developing it may be useful to log out all requests and responses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/connecting.html#complex-logging).

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. (I tried to upvote but I need a score of 15)

Comment: No problem. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately this relies on my calling the Search method in order to see what's in my request, in my original query I could see what I was ABOUT to send without actually sending it, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, pass your request to `client.Serializer.SerializeToString(request);` for json string or `client.Serializer.SerializeToBytes(request)` for a byte array

Comment: Note that the `SerializeToString` and `SerializeToBytes` are extension methods and you need a `using Elasticsearch.Net;`

Answer (score 1):

Serialize method now requires stream, on which it will write raw json query - Working properly For Nest 5.3.0 :

```
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        nestClient.Serializer.Serialize(query, stream);
        var jsonQuery = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```