# Serialize query from Nest client ElasticSearch 6.4

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.net

Till ElasticSearch 6.0 we were able to serialize the search request (object of SearchRequest) to a string

```
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            ElasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(searchRequest, mStream);
            string rawQueryText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
        }
```

Example is here too [serialize query from Nest client elastic search 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551724/serialize-query-from-nest-client-elastic-search-2-3)

But in 6.4 version that has been removed and I am not able to locate exactly where is the documentation to serialize the query with 6.4 version
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the extension method in [ElasticsearchSerializerExtensions](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7abc99db235996e46b6bbef703bd8c54cef08096/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Serialization/IElasticsearchSerializer.cs#L25-L42) in Elasticsearch.Net

```
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Nest;

var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    Query = new MatchAllQuery()
};

var json = client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(searchRequest);
```